# Which of the following show hyperconjugation

Tags: organic-chemistry, hyperconjugation

[image]

None of the given compounds have any alpha hydrogen to show hyperconjugation, but the given answer is c.

Comment: I pick a black bear in a coal mone. Please draw the structures in rather than relying on screenshots. You shoukd have software that can do so.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've only considered one resonance form of compound C. If you consider the other major resonances, there are alpha C-H bonds that can participate in hyperconjugative effects:

[image: hyperconjugation]